What words are similar to dilettante in pronunciation or spelling?
What words are similar to dilettante in pronunciation or spelling? Like for misspeaking or miswriting, i.e. malapropism , paronymic attraction, rhyme, ...

If you don't mind French, "de la tante" means "of the aunt".

My father, to my surprise, pronounced it correctly (it's Italian in origin) when he warned me, when I was 16, that if I smoked cigarettes using a holder (like Noël Coward) people would 'think that I was a dilettante'. He mean 'homosexual'.

@MichaelHarvey why was the association?

In the 1930s, in England, when my father was a teenager, it was a cliché or stereotype that gay men, especially those who worked in the theatrical field,  smoked using cigarette holders. A well-known actor and musician, Noël Coward, famously conformed to this stereotype.

@MichaelHarvey why was dilettante associated with that

@MichaelHarvey where was dilettante in the story?

'Dilettante' not only had its normal meaning (person of either sex who is an amateur or beginner at something, usually something arts related); it was also understood by many as a euphemism for 'homosexual man'. In that period, male homosexuality in Britain was so taboo that it was not even named directly.

My father told me a joke from that time, about a 'theatrical type' (or 'dilettante') who had done his duty in 1914 and volunteered to serve on the Western Front. He survived the war, and when he was asked what it was like in the trenches, exclaimed 'My dear! The noise! And the people!'

Delectant is a possibility. It means delight, charm or please.

delectant (Latin)
Verb
dēlectant
Inflection of dēlectō (third-person plural present active indicative)


delecto (Latin) Verb
delight, charm, please

wordsense explains delectant

Thanks. How did you find it? Is there a tool that can help you in things like this? Is delectant a word in English?
